# undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my `user.rb` file under `models`, I defined a method `full-name`, and called this method in my views. It raises this error that I do not know how to solve.

```
NoMethodError in Statuses#index
Showing app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #24 raised:
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #10):

def full_name
  first_name + " " + last_name
end
```

Rails.root:

```
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/user.rb:10:in `full_name'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:24:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1801360389632919652_70105866374460'
<li>
  <%= link_to current_user.full_name, edit_user_registration_path %>
</li>
```

Comment: `full-name` is an invalid method name. What is your question?

Answer (score 4):

Your `first_name` attribute contains `nil`.

Since `NilClass` does not implement `+` method, it raises an error. One way to handle that would be to cast values to string:

```
first_name.to_s + " " + last_name.to_s
```

But the better, idiomatic way is to use string interpolation:

```
def full_name
  "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
```

To see the actual value that is contained in a variable you could use

```
puts first_name
```

But, since the `nil` value would become an empty string when printed, it would look the same as `""`, a blank string. To see if the value is actually `nil` when printing, you can use

```
puts first_name.nil?
# => true
```

or

```
puts first_name.class
# => NilClass
```

Comment: So is that means string+string in invalid?

Comment: No, that means `nil` + string is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is right, just you have one (or more) record with empty value in first_name (and/or empty last_name).
As Nic explained Ruby does not have automatic cast from nil to string, but I suppouse you want to some value for those fields, so I suggest you to use a proper validation for them:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true
end
```